# The сonstraints do not work on an iPad with collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, storyboard, constraints

I am using a collection view in a storyboard and I need one ribbon with an image in the center of the screen. Constraints work fine on iPhone, but not iPad. How can this be done?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The collectionView cell size is not specified for different screen sizes.

Use UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout's method

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
                      layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, 
               sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout/1617708-collectionview